# Does a constructor in c++ code return any object?

Tags: c++

The problem is not exactly as the question. The real question is: why did my code work?

I posted this question on stackoverflow->[make objects in function arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67766900/can-an-object-be-constructed-in-place-of-an-argument-in-c-like-we-do-in-java/67771690#67771690). What I asked is whether you can do something similar to:

```java
....
// java code
Obj o1 = new Obj(new Objectt()); // we made and passed a new object in a function argument
// OR
returned = function_does_something(new objeect());
....
```

in c++? I.e .

```cpp
returned = function_does_something(new objectt()); // possible in c++?
```

Note that in the question I asked (link above), the following code worked

```cpp
store.insert(store.begin(), vector<int>({key, value})); // type(store) = vector<vector<int>>
```

What I had thought during that time was that: call constructor to obtain a new object.
`vector<int>({values})` was the constructor I called. But in c++, a constructor does not return anything, right? So why did the code work?

Comment: It does not return anything; not even void. `new` returns the address of the object created on free store. It is not clear what you do not understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A constructor doesn't return anything, but nevertheless C++ lets you declare a temporary/anonymous object as an argument to a function, in certain cases.  An object declared this way will be constructed on the stack just before the function is called, passed to the function, and then destroyed immediately after the function returns.

So in this case the code is declaring a temporary/anonymous object `vector<int>({key, value})` as an argument to `store.insert()`.  It's a bit more convenient that the alternative explicit/named-declaration syntax that would accomplish the same thing:

```
 {
    const vector<int> someTemporaryObjectName12345({key,value});
    store.insert(store.begin, someTemporaryObjectName12345);
 }
```

(note that I put the curly-braces there just to ensure that `someTemporaryObjectName12345` gets destroyed immediately after `store.insert()` returns, to match the temporary/anonymous syntax's behavior; without them `someTemporaryObjectName12345` wouldn't be destroyed until the end of the containing scope)

The temporary/anonymous object-declaration syntax above will work as long as the function-parameter is of type `vector<int>` or `const vector<int> &` (and more generally, for any passed-by-value argument or passed-by-const-reference argument of any type that matches the anonymous-object's type)

Comment: So what happened in my code was that ````vector<int>({values}) // name = obj```` created a temporary object. This entire object was copied into a new object which was added in the vector. And then "obj" was destroyed with its copy in the vector?

Comment: And I did not call the constructor?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what [Jeremy Friesner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/131930/jeremy-friesner) said in their [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67799481/4944425), I'd like to add that one of the overloads of `std::vector::insert` has the following signature (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert):

> ```
> iterator insert( const_iterator pos, T&& value );           //     (since C++11)  
>                                                             //(2)  (until C++20)  
> constexpr iterator insert( const_iterator pos, T&& value ); //     (since C++20)
> ```

That allows the temporary object constructed by `vector<int>({key, value})` to be moved<sup>(1)</sup> into the new element of the vector `store`, while a `T const& value` argument would have required a copy.

Also, please note that the Standard Library offers other containers like [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) or [`std::unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) to deal with key-value pairs.

---

(1) [What is move semantics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-is-move-semantics)